# Exp. Stability of perturbed system with temporally vanishing perturbation

Tags: dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I have a perturbation problem for which I can't find a fitting theorem in Khalil's Nonlinear Systems. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction:

Given a nominal system

$\dot x(t) = A(t)x(t)$

which is exponentially stable and a perturbed system

$\dot x(t) = A(t)x(t)+g(t)$

where $g(t)$ is bounded and as $t\rightarrow \infty$ converges exponentially to zero.

I imagine that the perturbed system is exponentially stable as well.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is not true.

Consider $\dot x = -x +e^{-3t}$.

The solution is $x=c_1e^{-t}-0.5e^{-3t}$ with $c_1=x_0+0.5$.

So $\|x\|$ has a part that is independent from $x_0$, which means that for arbitrarily small $\|x_0\|$, the exponential stability condition breaks.

Comment: why does it break? Exp. stability basically says that you can fit an exponent from above and below such that your solution never exits created tunnel. I can think of such an exponential for any $|x_0|$.